# Is there a Mobile Touch Event Plugin for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I know that jQuery Mobile comes bundled with lots of useful events for mobile devices. However, I don't want to have to include all of the additional plugins that come as part of the entire jQuery Mobile package.

My question is simple:

**Has anyone come across a good plugin for stand-alone jQuery that adds touch device events?** 
Something like:

```
$(this).tap();
$(this).taphold();
$(this).swipeleft();
$(this).swiperight();
$(this).doubletap();
```

I know that I could write a plugin myself to achieve this, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if it's already been done...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just wanted to point out that I eventually wrote my own library for this:

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events

Answer (score 2):

There are some plugins that handle this I've been looking at recently:

- http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library
- http://jgestures.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/auchenberg/jquery.touchEvents
- http://alexgibson.github.com/shake.js/
- https://github.com/alexgibson/WKTouch

Have you already found something that worked for you?