# swipe gestures and Wordpress templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm looking to do a mobile web app in Wordpress. I need the template to have a thin (~3/4 inch) horizontal rectangular section at the very top that can be swiped to the left/right to serve as the navigation. Basically, every time you swipe this section to the right/left, it changes the page below it. I've seen templates where the whole page swipes, but not split in this was as I described it here. If anyone has any pointers for me on how to customize the template like this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: there are some plugins for jQuery that handle gestures like swipes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981274/mobile-event-plugin-for-jquery. i guess those could be combined with something like http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ quite easily...

Comment: This question below has 1/2 of the solution I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024523/trying-to-make-navigation-bar-for-tablet-site

To recap: Trying to make a type of swiping navigation, similar to Android Google Play. Basically a thin bar at top which swipes at a different rate than swiping of the content below it. You swipe the content to L or R and the top bar also moves, but slower/faster (depending).

It's similar to the solution above, except there are two horizontal regions that are related and are swiping/moving at the same time. Do you think it can be done?

Comment: Here's my 1/2 working solution: http://www.webitap.com/saba/mytest/index_2.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [this plugin](https://github.com/pommiegranit/gestures/archive/master.zip). They support Swipe left, right, up, down and double tap. you can specify the area where you want wordpress to register the gestures, say in your case it would be the ID of the Div you want user to swipe in. Let me know if you face any difficulty.